# Reflection and generic types

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I'm writing some code for a class constructor which loops through all the properties of the class and calls a generic static method which populates my class with data from an external API. So I've got this as an example class:

```
public class MyClass{
  public string Property1 { get; set; }
  public int Property2 { get; set; }
  public bool Property3 { get; set; }

  public static T DoStuff<T>(string name){
    // get the data for the property from the external API
    // or if there's a problem return 'default(T)'
  }
}
```

Now in my constructor I want something like this:

```
public MyClass(){
  var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();
  foreach(PropertyInfo p in properties){
    p.SetValue(this, DoStuff(p.Name), new object[0]);
  }
}
```

So the above constructor will thrown an error because I'm not supplying the generic type.

So how do I pass in the type of the property in?

Comment: Sorry the question is kind of confusing, is there some typos in the second code snippet?

Comment: Yeah, I think you meant to write "MyClass.DoStuff(p.Name)" as the second parameter to p.SetValue().

Comment: Yeah, I did a mistake in the 2nd code snippet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use reflection to call generic Method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do you want to call DoStuff<T> with T = the type of each property? In which case, "as is" you would need to use reflection and MakeGenericMethod - i.e.

```
var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo p in properties)
{
    object value = typeof(MyClass)
    .GetMethod("DoStuff")
    .MakeGenericMethod(p.PropertyType)
    .Invoke(null, new object[] { p.Name });
    p.SetValue(this, value, null);
}
```

However, this isn't very pretty. In reality I wonder if it wouldn't be better just to have:

```
static object DoStuff(string name, Type propertyType);
... and then
object value = DoStuff(p.Name, p.PropertyType);
```

What does the generics give you in this example? Note that value-types will still get boxed etc during the reflection call - and even then boxing [isn't as bad as you might think](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/10/08/why-boxing-doesn-t-keep-me-awake-at-nights.aspx).

Finally, in many scenarios, TypeDescriptor.GetProperties() is more appropriate than Type.GetProperties() - allows for flexible object models etc.

Answer (score 7):

Was your constructor code meant to read like this:

```
public MyClass(){
  var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();
  foreach(PropertyInfo p in properties){
    p.SetValue(this, DoStuff(p.Name), new object[0]);
  }
}
```

? Note the `DoStuff` instead of `MyClass`.

If so, the problem is that you're trying to use generics when they're really not applicable. The point of generics (well, one of the points) is to use compile-time type safety. Here you don't know the type at compile time! You could call the method by reflection (fetching the open form and then calling [MakeGenericMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx)) but that's pretty ugly.

Does `DoStuff` really need to be generic in the first place? Is it being used from elsewhere? The parameter to `PropertyInfo.SetValue` is just object, so you'd still get boxing etc even if you *could* call the method generically.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use DoStuff from another place, I also suggest to write a non-generic method.

Maybe you created the generic method to be able to use default(T). To replace that in a non-generic method, you can use Activator.CreateInstance(T) for value types and null for reference types:

```
object defaultResult = type.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(type) : null
```