# Recursive call on generic method with new type from PropertyInfo?

Tags: c#, reflection, recursion

I have a customer class with a sub-class address

```
internal class Customer    
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    [ObjectDefRelation(isSubClass = true)]
    public Addressinformation Addressinformation { get; set; }
}

internal class Addressinformation 
{
    public string street { get; set; }
}
```

I have a Method to fill this object with data from a xml. Now I want to call this method recursive when its arrive the sub-class `Addressinformation`. How can I call my generic method with informations from `PropertyInfo`?

```
public static T ConvertXmlToClass<T>(XmlDocument xmlDocumentObjectDef, XmlNode xmlNode, ObjectDefRelationAttribute parentClass = null) where T : new()
{
    ObjectDefRelationAttribute defRelationAttribute;
    T xmlToClass = new T();

    foreach (PropertyInfo field in xmlToClass.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        foreach (Attribute attr in field.GetCustomAttributes(true))
        {
            defRelationAttribute = attr as ObjectDefRelationAttribute;
            if (null != defRelationAttribute)
            {
                if (defRelationAttribute.isSubClass)
                {
                    // 
                    // here I need help to call the recursive method (XXX)
                    //
                    var subClass = Helper.ConvertXmlToClass<XXX>(xmlDocumentObjectDef, xmlNode, defRelationAttribute);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used the best answer with some modification:

```
Type typeArguments = GetType(field.PropertyType.Namespace + "." + field.PropertyType.Name);
object value = typeof(Helper).GetMethod("ConvertXmlToClass").MakeGenericMethod(typeArguments).Invoke(null, new object[] {xmlDocumentObjectDef, xmlNode, defRelationAttribute});
```

Comment: how can I call my generic method with informations from PropertyInfo?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use reflection to call generic Method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you've got a function that converts Type names to Types, something like this:

```
Type GetType(string typeName)
{
    return Type.GetType(typeName);
}
```

then you can call this method as:

```
object value = typeof(owningType).GetMethod("ConvertXmlToClass").MakeGenericMethod(GetType(typeName)).Invoke(xmlDocumentObjectDef, xmlNode, xmlToClass);
```

and Use `PropertyInfo.SetValue()` to set it on the property

Comment: thanks it works with some modification. have a look to my question

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with your current approach then you need to use reflection to built the generic method call from the `field.PropertyType` as described here: [Reflection and generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196936/reflection-and-generic-types)

However you could also consider changing your method to accept a `Type` as parameter instead of making a generic method (hint you can use `Activator.CreateInstance(type)` to instantiate an object).

Comment: I don't want to set the value. how to do that is clear. I need to call this method recursive because there are lots of functions in it for getting the informations from xml

Comment: That's what I said: You need to built your method call with reflection at runtime, like this: `typeof(Helper).GetMethod("ConvertXmlToClass").MakeGenericMethod(field.PropertyType);` - it's described in the answer to the question I linked to.