# Specify generics type using a field

Tags: c#, generics, datarow, typeof, gettype

Suppose I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public decimal myDecimal;
    public string myString;
}
```

I want to use the DataRowExtensions method [Field<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx)

Currently, I am using the class like so:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.myDecimal = row.Field<decimal>("MyDecimalColumnName");
myClass.myString = row.Field<string>("MyStringColumnName");
```

However, if I ever decide to change the type of myDecimal to something other than `decimal`, I want the call to `row.Field` to reflect the correct data.

I want something similar to the following syntax:

```
myClass.myDecimal = row.Field<typeof(myClass.myDecimal)>("MyDecimalColumnName");
```

This doesn't compile, and I have no idea how to use `typeof` or `GetType()` to just return `decimal`, whatever that would be called.

Is there a way to do this, or something similar?  I figured this could accomplished at compile time as the types are already known, and since generics are compile time constructs.

Thanks!

Comment: have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/196936/754438)

Comment: Can't the compiler *infer* that type parameter?

Comment: @davisoa not for *return* values, no

Comment: Oh, that's the restriction, I wasn't sure.

Comment: Why not just `row.Field<myClass.myDecimal>("MyDecimalColumnName")` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, note that public fields are usually a very bad idea; but if we assume this was a private backing field, there are 2 interesting options here;

The first is to exploit generic type inference; this doesn't work for the **return** type, but does for the parameters, so you could have:

```
row.GetField("MyDecimalColumnName", out obj.someField);
```

where that is:

```
GetField<T>(string name, out T value);
```

Another trick would be to use implicit operators, i.e. have `GetField(string)` return a dummy object that has implicit conversion operators to a few types such as `int`, `decimal`, etc, and do the work / conversion in the operator. A bit hacky, but would work - syntax would be:

```
myClass.myDecimal = row.Field("SomeColumn")
```

with:

```
SomeDummyType GetField(string name);
```

and with `SomeDummyType` having an implicit static conversion operator or several.

However! IMO the *best* option here is to use a tool such as an ORM or micro-ORM to load the values for you, and don't use `DataRow` at all.

Another simple option is just to go old-school:

```
myClass.myDecimal = (decimal)row["SomeColumn"];
```

I mean - is the `.Field<T>` really helping you all that much? Do you genuinely refactor your classes often enough that this is worth worrying about it?

Comment: I like your `row.GetField` suggestion, though I'm wondering why I can't explicitly set the type of return values.  As for using `Field<T>`, I use it because it helps using nullable types (the DataRow returns `DBNull.Value` for nullable columns, and `null` for columns that are non-existant).  For example `decimal? x = (decimal?)row["MyColumn"]` will fail if MyColumn is null, but will NOT fail if MyColumn is non-existant.

Comment: @Matthew yes, don't get me started on that craziness; I am not a fan of `DBNull.Value`

Comment: @Matthew of course it won't work quite as conveniently when you've fixed your code by getting rid of those public fields. Hint. Hint Hint. Hint.

Comment: Yea I know using public fields is generally bad form, but these objects are just POCO.

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection to dynamically construct the proper generic method:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
var myType = typeof(MyClass.myDecimal);
var myMethod = Type.GetType("System.Data.DataRowExtensions")
   .GetMethod("Field", new[]{typeof(DataRow), typeof(string));
var genericMethod = myMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[]{myType});

myClass.myDecimal = genericMethod.Invoke(row, new object[]{"MyDecimalColumnName"});
```

Comment: I would probably italicize the _could_ on that. Yes it works but definitely isn't an optimal solution.