# c#: check if a 'ref' argument actually comes from a static variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to check from within a function if an argument is a static variable?

**This would help me prevent any possibility of typos** where the user tries to quickly setup a singleton, but forgets to declare his own `instance` member as `static` before supplyng it to us via `ref`

here is my function:

```
// returns 'false' if failed, and the object will be destroyed.
// Make sure to return from your own init-function if 'false'.
public static bool TrySet_SingletonInstance<T>(this T c,  ref T instance) where T : Component {

    //if(instance is not static){ return false } //<--hoping for something like this

    if(instance != null){  
        /* cleanup then return */
        return false;  
    }
    instance = c;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: well,  if not possible, - one way to do this would be to use a different argument-name. For example `ref T instance_VERIFY_IS_STATIC`.  Yes, ugly, but will sober-up anyone who tries to use our function

Comment: I think you can use reflection to get information about T see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196936/reflection-and-generic-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume that your singleton classes have one and only one static instance (which makes sense, since it's *single*ton), we can find the field using the type. In which case there is actually no need to pass it in a reference to it at all. And since we know how to get the FieldInfo, we can tell if it is static via Reflection.

```
public static bool TrySet_SingletonInstance<T>(this T c) where T : Component
{
    //Find a static field of type T defined in class T 
    var target = typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).SingleOrDefault(p => p.FieldType == typeof(T));

    //Not found; must not be static or public, or doesn't exist. Return false.
    if (target == null) return false;

    //Get existing value
    var oldValue = (T)target.GetValue(null);

    //Old value isn't null. Return false.
    if (oldValue != null) return false;

    //Set the value
    target.SetValue(null, c);

    //Success!
    return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
var c = new MySingleton();
var ok = c.TrySet_SingletonInstance();
Console.WriteLine(ok);
```

See a working example here: [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sa2e3p)

Comment: What I fail to understand, why would you have a method to set the singleton instead of having the singleton assignment in the ctor? I don't see the added value in this. If the point is just to know if the assignment went through, then you can check if(c == MySingleton.Instance), that'd tell you if the singleton points to that instance object. I feel the problem is more in the design of the OP.

Comment: A better question is [why would you use a singleton at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755539/why-is-singleton-considered-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: I am using Unity, and had some problems with constructors for a long time.  If I remember, they were called at various inconvenient times during editor, so after countless hours of hacking I moved code to other Runtime-only init functions. It was all about initialization, and the order of many script initializations that had to be spaced out over at least 2 frames. Perhaps there was something else that don't remember.